# Sending Private Messages on Facebook

Tags: facebook

My mother is new to Facebook (and I don't have one) and she is wondering how to send a private message to a Facebook friend so that no other fried can see the message. Can anyone please post a method to do this. Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question. This *may* be a better fit at [webapps.se]. Be sure to read their [FAQ](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help) before posting to make sure your question meets their requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private messages on Facebook are sent through Facebook Messenger.

If your mother is using a tablet or mobile phone then she should download the Messenger app from her device's app store. Once she has downloaded and logged in to the app, she can find instructions for how to send a private message on the following page: https://www.facebook.com/help/messenger-app/ipad/258606324230105?helpref=platform_switcher. Note the subheadings ('Messenger for Android', 'Messenger for Iphone' etc) which contain device specific instructions.

If your mother is using a computer then the following link from the Facebook Help Centre will guide her through the process: https://www.facebook.com/help/154917244574299